# Stored Procedure doesn't return records when called from C#, but works in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that correctly returns records when I call it from a SSMS query.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[q_CheckRecords]
    @ItemIDS AS VARCHAR(40)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT * 
    FROM q_Warehouse80_OOS_ItemsNeedingNotification 
    WHERE item_id  = @ItemIDS
END
```

Calling this from a SSMS query like this:

```
exec [q_CheckOOSWarehouse80ItemsNeedingNotification] 'B30-R10000-B001'
```

It correctly returns a row, however when I use this C# code to call the stored procedure, I never get any rows returned.

```
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = null;

 conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=" + sSessionServer + ";database=" + sSessionDatabase + "; Integrated Security=SSPI");

  String SQL = "[q_CheckOOSWarehouse80ItemsNeedingNotification]";

  cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = SQL;
  cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemIDS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ItemsToBeChecked;

  conn.Open();
  myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  // check to see if any rows were returned.
  if (myReader.HasRows)
  {
       while (myReader.Read())
       {                                   
            // code to read fields in returned rows here
       }
  }

  conn.Close();
```

It appears to be a problem with how C# defines the datatype being passed to the stored procedure, but I haven't found any information online on how to solve this problem.

If I were to changed the stored procedure so it's "hard coded"

```
@ItemIDS AS VARCHAR(40)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    select * from q_Warehouse80_OOS_ItemsNeedingNotification where item_id  =  'B30-R10000-B001'
END
```

then the C# call to it correctly indicates that a row was "found".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is type of ItemsToBeChecked variable?

Comment: try without the brackets:  String SQL = "q_CheckOOSWarehouse80ItemsNeedingNotification";

Comment: Can you format your code correctly? It's painful for the eyes.

Comment: SQL is not formatted, but you can look by trying 
`var myparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemIDS", SqlDbType.VarChar);
myparam.Value = "ItemsToBeChecked";`

Comment: try to specify  the size for parameter `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemIDS", SqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value`

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to observe it execute the query and pass in the parameter.

Comment: I added the length to the .Add call without any successful results :(

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify the length of a `varChar` [sql treats it as length 1](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemIDS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ItemsToBeChecked;
```

Your variable `ItemsToBeChecked` will be truncated, and I suspect there is nothing matching in your database with just the first character of that value.

Specify the length of the varchar

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemIDS", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = ItemsToBeChecked;
```

You can verify this is the case by putting a profiler on sql, and executing your c#. You will see the value passed to the `@ItemIDS` parameter is only 1 character long.

Comment: I added the length to the .Add call without any successful results

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because you are not calling your stored procedure in your C# Code.

Comment: I'm not ? Why do you say that ?